# Check for unique constraint inside the save method

Tags: python, django

I have a model on which the unique_together parameter is not working. The reason is that most of the times the "client_repr" variable is set on the save() method.
If someone creates a task with the same ('client_repr', 'task_type'... ) combination the model won't detect it because the "client_repr" value is null until the end of the save() method.

How can i call for a unique constraint verification inside the save() method?

```
class Task(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name = 'tasks', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    b_client = models.ForeignKey(BClient, related_name = 'tasks', on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    client_repr = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True, blank = True)
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name = 'tasks', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    extra_fields = models.ManyToManyField(ExtraField, blank = True)
    spot = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('client_repr', 'task_type', 'task_description', 'department'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return ' | '.join([f'{self.client_repr}', f'{self.task_description}', f'{self.task_type}'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.b_client:
            self.client_repr = str(self.client)
        else:
            self.client_repr = str(self.b_client)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know i could just make a search (ex: if Task.objects.get(...): ) but is it the most django-pythonic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Using `clean()`

It's not directly what you asked, but it's generally more django-friendly and does not require weird things like overriding `save()`

```
class Task(Model):

    def clean():
        # your code starts here
        if not self.b_client:
            self.client_repr = str(self.client)
        else:
            self.client_repr = str(self.b_client)
        # your code ends here
```

Since this custom `clean()` is called **before** django calls `validate_unique()`, it should fulfill your requirements.

See the [details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) in the official documentation.

### Option 2: Continue doing everything in `save()`

To check unique constraints, you can do the following:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...  # your code that automatically sets some fields
    try:
        self.validate_unique()
        # self.full_clean()  # <- alternatively, can use this to validate **everything**, see my comments below
    except ValidationError:
        # failed
        # that's up to you what to do in this case
        # you cannot just re-raise the ValidationError because Django doesn't expect ValidationError happening inside of save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note:

- doing only `self.validate_unique()` does not guarantee, that the updated earlier in `save()` values are good and don't violate something else
- `self.full_clean()` is safer, but will be slightly slower (how slow - depends on the validators you have)

### Documentation

Django [documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects):

> There are four steps involved in validating a model:
>
> - Validate the model fields - Model.clean_fields()
> - Validate the model as a whole - Model.clean()
> - Validate the field uniqueness - Model.validate_unique()
> - Validate the constraints - Model.validate_constraints()
>
> All four steps are performed when you call a model’s [full_clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what i was looking for. Also nice piece of information you just shared about the whole clean() method! :D

Comment: Thanks @art for sharing the extra information around how the full_clean method works. Much helpful